# How to put a element under flexboxes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to put the footer under two flexboxes (right & left).
But my code does not work correctly. Is there something wrong in my code.

```
#all{
    position: absolute;
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#left{
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#right{
    width: 20%;
}

footer{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The abstract of my HTML is below;

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="all">
        <div id="left">
        </div>

        <div id="right">
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>some words</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you include your html code? Or, it is better to include a workable code snippet, jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: I added the abstract of the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related with flex box. The `footer` is not displayed under 2 flexboxes (`#all`) because `#all`'s position is `absolute`, which makes it detached from page flow. In order to make `footer` display under `#all`, you need to remove the `absolute` code.

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/scmu8cw0/) for your code example, please check.

For more information on `absolute` and page `flow`, please check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements.